# Getting count of empty object on two different servers are different..!

Tags: php, object, count, server

```
I am getting count of empty object as a '0' on local server and count of same empty obejct as a '1' on different server using PHP.

Can anybody give me some information whether we can set count start value in PHP or what is the reason behind this.

BElow is the sample xml : 

<customer>
 <name></name>
 <address></address>
 <Contact>
  <!--<Mobile></Mobile>-->
  <!--<Mobile></Mobile>-->
  <Work></Work>
  <Home></Home>
</Contact>
</customer>
```

I am constructing the objet from the above xml and then fetching the value from that object.

Ex :  Like : $object->customer->contact->Mobile

The issue raise If i dont have Mobile tag in xml for :

var_dump($object->customer->contact->Mobile);

Comment: More information is needed. Please show a little about the object. Post the output from `var_dump($the_empty_object)`  as generated by both systems.

Comment: Provide a piece of code that reproduces this problem exactly.

Comment: Do you have SPL installed in one location and not in the other?  DOes the object implement `Countable` interface?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : 

LOCAL : object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]

ANOTHER SERVER : object(SimpleXMLElement)#61 (0) { }

Comment: Above are the two outputs i am getting for var dump.

Comment: Please edit above to add new information. You appear to be using SimpleXML. So it's important also to post a sample of the XML.  Are you _starting_ with the same XML on both systems?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Yes i am using the same xml on both systems and getting the two different out for the var_dump.

Yes will provide the sample xml shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read these excerpts from `count()` documentation:

> For objects, if you have SPL installed, you can hook into count() by
>   implementing interface Countable. The interface has exactly one
>   method, Countable::count(), which returns the return value for the
>   count() function.

And...

> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter
>   is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface,
>   1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is
>   NULL, 0 will be returned.

If you don't have SPL installed in one place and/or don't have class which implements `Countable` interface, you will likely get unexpected results.

Edit: I see you are using SimpleXMLElement here. It does not implement `Countable`, so you should not be trying to `count()` it.

Comment: I agree but as i mentioned above the values of the obejct for var dump are also getting different  1) object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
2) object(SimpleXMLElement)#61 (0) { }

Comment: @W.A.C Again, do you have SPL installed in one environment and not in the other? The fact that you are getting different results in different environments underscores the need to do something else here rather than use `count()`. I would focus on fixing that problem rather then spending time trying to determine why one environment returns different results than another.

Comment: SPL is installed on Linux server. But the local windows server i dont know how to check that SPL is enabled or not. Can you help.
On linux i checked with **php -m|grep SPL**